# PrimeFaces - p:fileDownload PDF

Tags: java, primefaces, pdf

Olá,

Estou tentando fazer download de um PDF na minha aplicação mas não estou conseguindo.

Quando clico no botão de **Download** ao invés de efetuar o download está verificando no form se os campos obrigatórios foram preenchidos.

Se preencher todos os campos funciona normalmente.

**Segue a baixo o código:**

```
<h:form id="formTeste" >            
    <p:panel toggleable="true" id="pgFormTeste" header="Teste">
       <h:panelGrid columns="2">                                

           <p:outputLabel for="descricao" value="Descrição:" />
           <p:inputText value="#{testeController.teste.desc}" required="true" />

          <p:outputLabel value= "PDF:" />
          <p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false">
             <p:fileDownload value="#{testeController.getFile()}" />
          </p:commandButton> 
       </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>
 </form>
```

**Controller:**

```
private String pathPDF = System.getProperty("jboss.apps.data.dir") + File.separator + "sigeap" + File.separator + "001.pdf";

public void setFile(StreamedContent file) {    
    this.file = file;    
}    

public StreamedContent getFile() throws FileNotFoundException {    
    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(pathPDF);    
    file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", "001.pdf");   
    return file;    
}
```

Se consegui isso já resolve boa parte do meu problema...

Aproveitando, se alguém souber também como posso abrir o PDF que está em uma pasta no servidor diretamente no browser como faz o **PDFObject** ajudaria bastante também.

Obrigado

Comment: Tente `<p:commandButton value="Download" ajax="false" immediate="true">`

Comment: Muito Obrigado... Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como já dito no comentário, use a opção `immediate=true` no `commmandButton`.

Resposta também já validada em [outra pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958410/primefaces-disable-validation-on-cancel-button).

Comment: Muito obrigado. era isso mesmo. Sabe me dizer se tem como abrir esse mesmo arquivo diretamente no browser usando o **PDFObject**?

Comment: A pergunta deveria ser fechada como duplicada. Esse fórum segue as mesmas especificações do stack overflow original ?

Comment: Creio que não, porque a pergunta estava em inglês. Nem todo mundo fala os dois idiomas.

Comment: Não conheço PDFObject, apenas o media. Creio ser possível sim, mas via código no ManagedBeans.